# Order of data in SQLite database

Tags: sqlite

If I was to insert lots of rows into an empty table without primary key, nor any indexes. Varying number of rows might be inserted per transaction. Could I then be sure that a SELECT * FROM the_table; would retrieve the data in the same order on both Linux and Windows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot and should never rely on the order of rows in a result set from a query that does not have ordering constraints. Even on the same platform, same database. Even if it works in your tests.

Things like [`VACCUM`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html)ing your database (or some of the `auto_vaccum` modes I think) could change the relative block layout of your data and alter the result set even if nothing else has changed elsewhere (no inserts, no query plan change).

Comment: We could even say that vacuum would never be run, no data would ever be deleted. I get your point, though.

Comment: You'd have to also add that you won't ever change the sqlite version at all (not the slightest patch), use the same compiler on all environments to produce the code and you've checked the optimizer behaves exactly the same way, made extra sure that absolutely no asynchronous I/O is used in the engine, ... too much effort to keep the thing stable. If you data has a "natural" ordering, make your schema reflect that. If it doesn't, well, you shouldn't care :-)